Changing brackets in list
I have this list of data :
data = {{  
         {2.69`, 7.2`, 8.18`} -> 7.88`,
         {7.2`, 8.18`, 9.02`} -> 9.19`,
         {7.2`, 8.18`, 9.02`} -> 9.19`
       }}

and I want to have a list of data with different brackets:
data = {
        {{2.69`}, {7.2`}, {8.18`}} -> {7.88`},
        {{7.2`}, {8.18`}, {9.02`}} -> {9.19`},
        {{7.2`}, {8.18`}, {9.02`}} -> {9.19`}
       }

What is the solution?

What is the purpose of this rule?

In your first block of code ( data={{ ... }} ) , are the double curly braces ( {{ instead of { ) significant for the question ? If it is the case, it's quite impossible to guess what you want to do.

Map[List, data[[1]], {-1}]

(* {{{2.69},{7.2},{8.18}}->{7.88},{{7.2},{8.18},{9.02}}->{9.19},{{7.2},{8.18},{9.02}}->{9.19}} *)


data /. x_Real :> {x} // First


{{{2.69}, {7.2}, {8.18}} -> {7.88}, {{7.2}, {8.18}, {9.02}} -> 
{9.19}, {{7.2}, {8.18}, {9.02}} -> {9.19}}


More generally, for all numbers:
data /. x_?NumericQ :> {x} // First


Or equivalently : (data //First) /. x_Real :> {x}

I noticed the extra brace later :)

For something else using MapAt
MapAt[List, data[[1]], {{All, 1, All}, {All, 2}}]

->
{{{2.69}, {7.2}, {8.18}} -> {7.88}, {{7.2}, {8.18}, {9.02}} -> {9.19}, {{7.2}, {8.18}, {9.02}} -> {9.19}}

